# How do I create a partition for every day of the current year in mysql table

Tags: mysql

Actually I want to store data last three month from current date rest of record deleted. data having millions of record

Comment: Can you improve your question, becouse now it is hardly understandable?

Comment: this link will help you to understand the exact problem ...
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675412/how-to-partition-a-myisam-table-by-day-in-mysql?rq=1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use given query.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME1 (
  id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Ctime DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY id (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=286802795 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
  PARTITION BY RANGE( TO_DAYS(Ctime) ) (
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2011-04-02')),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2011-04-03')),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2011-04-04')),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2011-04-05')),
    PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2011-04-06')),
    PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2011-04-07'))
    );
```